# how to add a dynamic param

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

the jquery plugin that im using is this
http://code.google.com/p/jquery-in-place-editor/

if i have a table like this

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>first name </th>
<th>last name </th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="id">1</td>
<td class="fname">sarmen</td>
<td class="lname">mikey</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="id">2</td>
<td class="fname">john</td>
<td class="lname">angelo</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="id">3</td>
<td class="fname">sarmen</td>
<td class="lname">grande</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

and my js looked something like this

```
$("td.fname").editInPlace({
    url: 'ajax.php',
    params: '',
    show_buttons: true          
});
```

then lets say i click on the first record to edit it which is fname of sarmen. how can i pass a param that only accociates id 1 ? because if i do a query of lets say

```
"update tbl_users set fname = '$_POST['update_value']' where fname = '$_POST['original_html']'"
```

(note: im just showing an example so no need to clean posts if that was bothering you :)   )

if i run this query the fname of sarmen will update in two records rather than one. How can i only update to id of 1 being to update only one record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("table tr").each(function(i, el) { 

   var tdId = $(el).find("td.id");

   $(this).find("td.fname".editInPlace({
       url: 'ajax.php',
       params: 'id=' + $(tdId).text(),
       show_buttons: true              
    });

});
```

Comment: This is the correct way! Didn't notice it wasn't a function ;)

Comment: wow i cant believe this works. i have to study this peice very closely :) thank you you saved me alot of time.

Comment: you're welcome, I guess what is in the consulting is an example, always tries to include "ID" on the elements to make the search faster in the "DOM". '<table id="myTable">...</table>'

Answer (score 0):

you must add to params id from the first cell in row.

```
    $("td.fname").editInPlace({
     id = $(this).parents('tr').children('td:first-child').html();
     url: 'ajax.php',
     params: {id:id},
     show_buttons: true          
    });
```

and `$id = (int)$_POST['id'];` in php